# How to determine number of same neighbours in matrix?

Tags: java, matrix

I have an array of arrays of objects with enum either 1 or 0.
It may look something like this:

```
0 0 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

I want all members of a group that contains 1, to show the amount of members in the whole group:

```
0 0 3 0
0 3 3 0
0 0 0 1
```

Is there any known way how to find this out? I mean, I could probably write conditions for every case I need because I want to change numbers below 5, but it would be lengthy.

Comment: Why first row is `0 0 3 0`? It shouldn't be `0 0 2 0` since only two of its neighbors are `1`? Shouldn't second row be `0 2 3 0` and third `0 0 0 1`?

Comment: Can you explain your output in more detail? How did you calculate that rows are `0,0,3,0` and not `1,3,2,2`? What do you mean by `neighbour`? Are diagonal elements also neighbours? Is element you are checking also neighbour to itself?

Comment: Oh, I count it like whole. You can look at it like number of neighbours + 1.

Comment: @Wlad: If you also count diagonal as neighbors, then second row should be `0 3 4 0` last row should be `0 0 0 2` and if you don't, then @Christian is correct about the first two rows.

Comment: Diagonal are not neighbours. I count only neighbours of enum 1. Yes, elements is neighbour to itself. Enum 0 is like empty space, it just separate 1.

Comment: So how does the 1 on first row have two neighbors and itself, if diagonals aren't counted in?

Comment: I explained it all wrong, sorry, not my native language. I want to find out number of ones, separated by zeros.

Comment: So you want all members of a group to show the amount of members in the whole group?

Comment: Yes! That's right explanation.

Comment: Really this is if not hard, but serious and interesting algorithm. You will find all neighbors, remember them, and then increase their all values.

Comment: I don't get it. But my friend offered me that he will code this in haskell....I don't know haskell, but hopefully I will get the gist.

Comment: this is really interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reminds me of MineSweeper, somehow. One could easily use recursion here....

```
public class MatrixNeighborCount
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int array[][] = new int[][]{
            { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        };
        int result[][] = count(array);
        print(result);
    }

    private static void print(int array[][])
    {
        for (int r=0; r<array.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<array[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%3d", array[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private static int[][] copy(int array[][])
    {
        int result[][] = new int[array.length][];
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = array[i].clone();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int[][] count(int inputArray[][])
    {
        int result[][] = new int[inputArray.length][];
        for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = new int[inputArray[i].length];
        }

        int array[][] = copy(inputArray);
        for (int r=0; r<array.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<array[r].length; c++)
            {
                if (array[r][c] == 1)
                {
                    int count = count(array, r, c);
                    distribute(inputArray, result, r, c, count);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int count(int array[][], int r, int c)
    {
        if (!valid(array, r, c)) return 0;
        if (array[r][c] == 0) return 0;

        array[r][c] = 0;
        return 1 + 
            count(array, r-1, c) +
            count(array, r+1, c) +
            count(array, r, c-1) +
            count(array, r, c+1);
    }

    private static void distribute(
        int inputArray[][], int result[][], int r, int c, int value)
    {
        if (!valid(inputArray, r, c)) return;
        if (inputArray[r][c] == 0) return;
        if (result[r][c] != 0) return;
        result[r][c] = value;
        distribute(inputArray, result, r-1, c, value);
        distribute(inputArray, result, r+1, c, value);
        distribute(inputArray, result, r, c-1, value);
        distribute(inputArray, result, r, c+1, value);
    }

    private static boolean valid(int array[][], int r, int c)
    {
        if (r < 0) return false;
        if (r >= array.length) return false;
        if (c < 0) return false;
        if (c >= array[r].length) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**BUT** :

1. For "large" arrays, this will lead to a StackOverflowError
2. A solution with some collections could be more elegant

It might help if you described the actual data structures that you are working on, and what the final purpose of this program will be....

Comment: Data structure - ArrayList<ArrayList>. 
It will be framework for procedural generated maps. Maps could be large up to 500x500 or more...

Comment: Btw thanks for the code. It's night here already, but I will check it and test it tommorow. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved with a Union-Find algorithm. Your matrix is interpreted as a graph of non-zero nodes with bidirectional vertical and horizontal connections. The problem is then to find connected partitions of the graph while keeping track of the partition size. Here is a standalone solution:

```
public class So21503628 {
    private List<List<Integer>> matrix;
    private int h, w;
    private Map<Integer, Node> nodes = new HashMap<>();
    So21503628() {
        matrix = new ArrayList<>();
        matrix.add(Arrays.asList(0,0,1,0));
        matrix.add(Arrays.asList(0,1,1,0));
        matrix.add(Arrays.asList(0,0,0,1));
        h = matrix.size(); w = matrix.get(0).size();
    }
    void run() {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                Node xy = nodeAt(x, y);
                if (xy == null) continue;
                Node x1y = nodeAt(x+1, y);
                if (x1y != null) union(xy, x1y);
                Node xy1 = nodeAt(x, y+1);
                if (xy1 != null) union(xy, xy1);
            }
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                Node n = nodeAt(x, y);
                if (n == null) continue;
                matrix.get(y).set(x, find(n).count);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(matrix);
    }
    Node nodeAt(int x, int y) {
        if (x >= w || y >= h || matrix.get(y).get(x) == 0) return null;
        int xy = y * w + x;
        Node node = nodes.get(xy); 
        if (node == null) { node = new Node(); nodes.put(xy, node); }
        return node;
    }
    void union(Node n1, Node n2) { // unite areas if separate
        Node r1 = find(n1), r2 = find(n2);
        if (r1 != r2) { r2.parent = r1; r1.count += r2.count; }
    }
    Node find(Node n) { // find representative + compress path
        Node r = n; while (r.parent != null) r = r.parent;
        if (r != n) while (n.parent != r) { Node h = n.parent; n.parent = r; n = h; }
        return r;
    }
    static class Node { Node parent; int count = 1; }
    public static void main(String[] args) { new So21503628().run(); }
}
```

Union-Find scales very well (near O(n)).
For details on Union-Find, see [Disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) on Wikipedia.

Comment: For [[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]], output is [[0, 0, 1, 0], [2, 2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]]; which is incorrect. I haven't studied code yet, maybe it's just some small mistake.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it: Use `y<h` and `x<w` instead of `y<h-1` and `x<w-1` in first traversal and added check for x and y at `nodeAt()`. The `-1` was meant as optimization but led to not honoring vertical links at the right end and horizontal links at the bottom.

Comment: Your answer is better, but I don't understand it completely. I am making project for school and I have to know my code. I appreciate you found time to help me. Thank you.